# How to populate a Property's DescriptionAttribute from xml

Tags: c#, attributes, propertygrid

I would like to populate the DescriptionAttribute of a property, from a string that will be initialized from an xml file. The property will be used in a propertygrid.

The main thing is getting the descriptions from an xml file. How to get it into a const string that i can then use as the DescriptionAttribute of a property.

I have tried a few things with no success so any help would be appreciated.

or is there another wey to assign the xml values to the description? A typeconverter perhaps? Just point me to the right direction please.

```
public class1
{
    string BaboonDescription = "";
    string TigerDescription = "";
    const string SnakeDescription = "A snake is bla bla bla";

    // method that extracts the descriptions from the xml file.
    public void PopulateFromXml(string xmlfile)
    {
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlfile);
        var items = from i in xDoc.Descendants("item")
                    select i;

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            switch (item.Attribute("name").Value)
            {
                case "Baboon":
                    BaboonDescription = item.Value; // Assigns BaboonDescription the description from xml.
                    break;
                case "Tiger": 
                    TigerDesscription = item.Value; // Assigns TigerDescription the description from xml.
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class2 : class1
{
    [Description(BaboonDescription)] // problem here. Telling me that I need const string. But i have to get the strings from an xml.
    public string Baboon { get; set; }

    [Description("tiger is bla bla")] // this one works but I want the description from the xml.
    public string Tiger { get; set; }

    [Description(SnakeDescription)] // this also works but I want the description from the xml.
    public string Snake { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about "no success". What did you expect to happen? What happened instead?

Comment: You have to obey the rules of the language you use. If it needs const string then it must be so. Try to find other ways.

Comment: @tnw i tried populating a string from xml first then when the const string is created assign it the populated string. But got an error. i know it needs a const but is there a way around it where i can give it a string from an xml? Cause the descriptions are long. So i would like to keep them in an xml file for easy maintaining.

Answer (score 0):

[DescriptionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx) cannot be compiled and be dynamic at the same time.

Check out my answer to this SO question that demonstrates how to build a dynamic type descriptor: [Optimize class for PropertyGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033077/optimize-class-for-propertygrid)

With the DynamicTypeDescriptor class, you can build a wrapper class with description attributes you want.

Comment: thanks for your help. your optimize class gave me a few ideas to work on.