# Property Grid Custom Search Box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, propertygrid

I have a PropertyGrid with a lot of nested items. How can I make a searchbox to filter and display only the items matching the search string?

Comment: Pasty: I am currently passing focus manually to an item by using predefined strings. I would like to rather have a searchbox which can dynamically pull in "similar" items.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways -

Your best option is to implement [ICustomTypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx) interface and use the GetProperties() method to filter visible rows in PropertyGrid.

If you want to hack your way around - Using reflection set Browsable Attribute to false.  [Sample code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11383/Hiding-Inherited-Properties-from-the-PropertyGrid)

Here are some sample articles/links with code to implement ICustomTypeDescriptor -

http://wraithnath.blogspot.in/2011/01/implementing-icustomtypedescriptor-for.html

[PropertyGrid Browsable not found for entity framework created property, how to find it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422844/propertygrid-browsable-not-found-for-entity-framework-created-property-how-to-f)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189521/Dynamic-Properties-for-PropertyGrid